# Aplicar função limit em todas textareas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Eu estou impondo limite de caracteres em minhas textareas manualmente com esse código:

```
<textarea onKeyDown="limitText(this.form.message,this.form.countdown,240);" 
onKeyUp="limitText(this.form.message,this.form.countdown,240);"></textarea>
```

Porém cheguei a conclusão que ele suja e ocupa espaço. Gostaria de recorrer ao jQuery para poder aplicar essa função `limitText(this.form.message,this.form.countdown,240);` em todas as textareas existentes em meu site.

a função `limitText` é essa

```
function limitText(limitField, limitCount, limitNum) {
if (limitField.value.length > limitNum) {
    limitField.value = limitField.value.substring(0, limitNum);
} else {
    $("#countdown").html(limitField.value.length);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Atualmente, com HTML5 não é necessário utilizar scripts para limitar a quantidade de caracteres em um `<textarea>`, pode-se utilizar somente o atributo [`maxlength`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#attr-maxlength):

```html
<textarea maxlength='240'></textarea>
```

---

#### Resposta original:

Sua função `limitText` pode ter apenas dois parâmetros:

```
function limitText(limitField, limitNum){
   var content = "" + $(limitField).val(); // pega o valor na textarea.
   return content.length > limitNum ? content.substr(0, limitNum) : content;
}
```

Além dos eventos `keyup` e `keydown`, seria bom escutar o `keypress` também, para fazer a verificação mesmo se o usuário manter uma tecla pressionada.

```
$("textarea").bind("keypress keyup keydown", function(){
  $(this).val(limitText($(this), 240));
});
```

```css
textarea {width: 300px;border:2px solid #ccc}
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="Limite de caracteres: 240"></textarea>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function(){
    $("textarea").bind("keypress keyup keydown", function(){
      $(this).val(limitText($(this), 240));
    });
    
    function limitText(limitField, limitNum){
      var content = "" + $(limitField).val();
      return content.length > limitNum ? content.substr(0, limitNum) : content;
    }
  });
</script>
```